# Can someone explain what this n-queens code is doing?

Tags: java, n-queens

We were asked to do the n-queens problem in class, and I came across this bit of code online.  The deadline for our submission has already passed, and I turned in a solution that makes use of arrays, but this code interested me, as it required significantly less lines than my solution.  I'm not quite sure what is happening in the else statement, so if someone could explain, I would be greatly appreciative! Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NQueens {

private static int size;    //n
private static int mask;    //
private static int count;   //solutions

//Uses recursion to calculate the number of possible solutions, and increments "count".
public static void backtrack(int y, int left, int down, int right) {

    int bitmap;
    int bit;

    if (y == size) {
        count++;
    }
    else {
        bitmap = mask & ~(left | down | right);
        while (bitmap != 0) {
            bit = -bitmap & bitmap;
            bitmap ^= bit;
            backtrack(y + 1, (left | bit) << 1, down | bit, (right | bit) >> 1);
        }
    }
}

//main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of queens: ");
    size = keyboard.nextInt();
    count = 0;
    mask = (1 << size) - 1;
    backtrack(0, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println("The valid number of arrangements is " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give it here in loose terms with signposts to the details.

- What is the overall approach?

As the method name hints, `backtrack` implements a "backtracking" search for solutions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking That means that it drives down every possible path, making a decision about each branch whether the quest is still possible, abandoning any path the instant it is proven not to be viable, and backtracking to the most recent decision point to try another path. Quoting that Wikipedia article, regarding the N-queens problem, "In the common backtracking approach, the partial candidates are arrangements of `k` queens in the first `k` rows of the board, all in different rows and columns *[and diagonals -Ed.]*. Any partial solution that contains two mutually attacking queens can be abandoned."

By "partial candidate" we mean a sequence of placements of each queen starting with `k == 0` (solution still possible no matter what the next choice is), then `1` (fewer solutions possible because some choices put queens in attacking positions), then `2`, and so on until `N`. With each placement you put the queen in a new row, because obviously any previous row is not a viable choice.

- What is a "placement" in the algorithm?

To model placement of a queen in an `N`x`N` chess board, you need a data structure to represent that board, and whether a square is occupied, and whether two occupied squares are in a mutual attack relationship.

The data structure in the example is a bitmap. Here's where it gets tricky. You need to be familiar with bit manipulation to follow it.

```
private static int size;    //n
private static int mask;
private static int count;   //solutions
```

`size` is the number of queens, equal to the number of rows occupied.
`count` is the number of solutions found
`mask` is a sequence of `size` consecutive `1` bits, used to mask off `int` values to the size of the problem. In the eight-queens example, it will equal `0xff`, or `0b1111_1111`.

```
backtrack(int y, int left, int down, int right)
```

`y` is easy, it's the current number of queens placed so far, equivalently, the number of rows that have queens so far. The other three values use bit-operation trickery to reveal whether there are attack vectors computable in three directions. This is where it gets murky. I haven't gone all the way through it but I'll indicate how to proceed to full understanding.

```
bitmap = mask & ~(left | down | right);
```

Applies the `OR` operation between the arguments, and bit-flips the result.

```
bit = -bitmap & bitmap;
```

Takes the two's complement of the current value of `bitmap` (which will not be `0` here), and masks that against the original value.

```
bitmap ^= bit;
```

Applies the `XOR` operation to `bitmap` from the `bit` variable, which flips any bit in `bitmap` that has a `1` in the corresponding position in `bit`.

```
backtrack(y + 1, (left | bit) << 1, down | bit, (right | bit) >> 1);
```

Applies the recursion to the next queen (row), setting the new `left` to the old one merged with `bit` and shifted left to indicate looking at a new file ("file" in the chess sense). It shifts the `right | bit` merge to the right one to indicate a new file, and it leaves the `down | bit` merge indicating the current file.

Loosely the result of this is to zero out the positions that have mutual attack vectors. Every different combination of file placement is tried except ones that reach full `0` before all the queens have been placed.

Exactly how those bits indicate attack vectors is left as an exercise. How they migrate around the `size`-bit field is a matter of pencil-and-paper tracking the loop line by line.

EDIT: I didn't mention it, but this algorithm handles the diagonals, as is implicit in the rules.

EDIT: Results from a sample run of a version of the program:

```
size,  solutions,  backtracks,   millisec
   0,          1,           1,          0
   1,          1,           2,          0
   2,          0,           3,          0
   3,          0,           6,          0
   4,          2,          17,          0
   5,         10,          54,          0
   6,          4,         153,          0
   7,         40,         552,          0
   8,         92,        2057,          0
   9,        352,        8394,          0
  10,        724,       35539,          1
  11,       2680,      166926,          0
  12,      14200,      856189,         16
  13,      73712,     4674890,        116
  14,     365596,    27358553,        702
  15,    2279184,   171129072,       4318
  16,   14772512,  1141190303,      30321
  17,   95815104,  8017021932,     208300
```

Comment: First, thank you very much for your response.  I've read through it a few times and I feel like I'm starting to grasp how it works.  If you don't mind, I have a few specific questions regarding your answer:

First off, what is the point of the line of code that applies the `OR` operator and then flips the result? The code specifically is `bitmap = mask & ~(left | down | right);`

Also, and this may go with the question I just asked, what happens that allows the code to know if there are mutually attacking queens? What specifically is tested to find out if those collisions exist?

Thanks

Comment: I'm still figuring that part out. I have been tracing through the code in the debugger. Essentially the bit pattern in each `backtrack` call in each loop iteration represents one possible row of the chess board. A `0` is no queen placed. A `1` is a queen placed. With two queens, you have the bit pattern `00` with no queens yet placed. The first queen sets up either `01` or `10`. The next iteration examines a second row of `01` or `10`. but a `01` over a `01` is two queens in the same file - attack. `01` over `10` is a diagonal attack. No possible solutions.

Comment: With the `left`, `down`, and `right` bit manipulations, each rank examines its relationship to the preceding rank. The attack positions cause zeroes to appear. If a whole rank is all zeros then no further progress can be made. If that isn't the last rank, then it's not a solution. I'm still sussing out the exact bit manipulations, but I'm not going to post my analysis here. You need to figure it out for yourself. Stop asking SO to do your own work for you! You'll never be a real programmer that way. I'm doing this work now for me, not you.

Comment: I completely understand. Thank you for your help to this point. I understand the recursion and backtracking, but I just don't have any experience with bit manipulation, which is why I posted such specific questions. I apologize if you felt I was trying to exploit you in some way, as that was never my intention. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Just work through the loop with a debugger. I'll post a debuggable version that I'm using when I get a moment. I made it use instance methods. Give yourself about an hour at a time to explore with the debugger. It's the kind of experience you need to experience for yourself.

Comment: Before you do that, write yourself a little sample program with bit manipulations, and read up on the operators in the JLS. And what is this business about exploitation? Huh? I'm telling you what will be good for _you_! It isn't about me. Stop apologizing and start studying.